# Synchronized web browsing

Tags: web, synchronization

There exists several webapps that let you watch Youtube videos simultaneously with others syncing current time across all devices. E.g.: http://sync-video.com/

Is there such a thing but for web-browsing in general? I.e. it should let you multiple people browse the same web-site simultaneously, replicating user actions - like mouse clicks, touch events, key presses, filling inputs etc.

OS: Windows. License: Gratis/Freemium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked out [Rabb.it](https://www.rabb.it)?

It's a browser based app that lets you create a "Room" where other people can join and all view and interact with a virtualized Firefox browser. The browser is able to accept mouse and keyboard inputs, and everyone sees the same video stream of the virtual browser. It's free and just requires you to set up an account.